# perlbrew _Perl_xs_apiversion_bootcheck error with perl 5.22.2

Tags: perl, perlbrew

Using perlbrew to move from perl 5.16.0 to 5.22.2

Running on a MacBook Pro, OS X El Capitan

Install of new version of perl seemed to work just fine. However when I switch to 5.22.2 and attempt to run any of my scripts I see this error message.

> dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found:
>   _Perl_xs_apiversion_bootcheck   Referenced from: /Users/davidartus/perl5/lib/perl5/darwin-2level/auto/List/Util/Util.bundle
>   Expected in: dynamic lookup
>
> dyld: Symbol not found: _Perl_xs_apiversion_bootcheck   Referenced
>   from:
>   /Users/davidartus/perl5/lib/perl5/darwin-2level/auto/List/Util/Util.bundle
>   Expected in: dynamic lookup
>
> Trace/BPT trap: 5

I've seen that some folks have had similar errors when their paths have been incorrect. My path is set by perlbrew and looks plausible to me.

```
/Users/me/perl5/perlbrew/bin:/Users/me/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.22.2/bin:/Users/me/perl5/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Suggestions please.

Comment: I also get the same error with perlbrew trying to do a clean install of 5.26.1.

I resorted to the '--force' option to get around it, ie:


     perlbrew --force install 5.26.1

but I would like to know a better way to fix this.